# Get current request path from ActiveX control in VB6

Tags: vb6, activex

is there a way to get the current request path from an ActiveX control in VB6? I am wondering if VB6 has something similar to Request.Path in VB.NET.

The control is embeded in an HTML page using the OBJECT tag. I guess I could pass the current request path through PARAMs, but I just wanted to hear other options. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty simple if what you are after is the URL of the control's hosting page.

Have you tried `Parent.URL` or `Parent.URLUnencoded` yet?

Comment: @Bruno: Glad I caught your meaning, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveX component can call across [`IOleClientSite::GetMoniker`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181678) to do this, however this is difficult with VB6, you would need a custom type library implementing the interface at the very least.